# GGPlot2 , geom_point colors depending on sentiment Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Tags: r, twitter, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot tweets on a world map with colors depending on their sentiment. I know it should be really easy to do but I'm struggling to get it to work. When I try to view the map it gives me the error: "Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale"

```
#if(tweet.sentiment=="positive") {
 # mp = mp + geom_point(aes(x=tweet.x, y=tweet.y), colour = "blue", size=3)
#} else if(tweet.sentiment=="neutral") {
#  mp = mp + geom_point(aes(x=tweet.x, y=tweet.y), colour = "grey90", size=3)
#} else {
#  mp = mp + geom_point(aes(x=tweet.x, y=tweet.y), colour = "darkorange1", size=3)
#}


mp <- mp + geom_point(aes(x=tweetData$tweet.x, y=tweetData$tweet.y, colour=tweetData$tweet.sentiment), size=3) 

mp

Here's a sample of tweetData
         tweet.x    tweet.y  tweet.sentiment
1    -78.9429329  43.897545  negative
2    106.8227450  -6.174465  neutral
3    -84.3879824  33.748995  neutral
4   -118.2436849  34.052234  negative
5    -81.5157535  27.664827  positive
6    -88.7878678  43.784440  positive
7    -74.4056612  40.058324  negative
8    -95.7128910  37.090240  neutral
9    -80.8431267  35.227087  positive
```

Comment: You have a lot of extra code here, and we can't run it because we would need to provide our own twitter api credentials. Instead, please post the minimum code needed to reproduce the error. My guess is that you could cut this down considerable by just sharing an appropriate subset of `tweetData`, e.g. with posting the output of `dput(head(tweetData))`.

Comment: I'm guessing your world map (`mp` before you started the included snippet) has a colour scale in it already, which is causing the error. I can't replicate it using your sample data and `ggplot(tweetData, aes(tweet.x, tweet.y, colour = tweet.sentiment)) +  geom_point()`. You should add them all in one go like that then use `scale_colour_manual(values = c("darkorange1", "grey90", "blue"))`